# How do I wrap Unicode text containing ANSI color codes at word boundaries?

Tags: unicode, word-wrap, ansi-colors

How do I wrap Unicode text containing ANSI color codes at word boundaries?

I know of `grep -Eo ".{1,$w}"` to wrap Unicode text, but it does not respect word boundaries and ANSI codes.

Comment: Please add some data examples in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It seems this works:

```
cpanm App::ansifold
```

```
ansifold --boundary=word --width=100
```